# Customizing OAuth Error Responses in WSO2 Identity Server, Including Response from /oauth2/token API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am exploring options to customize OAuth error responses in WSO2 Identity Server and have a specific use case related to the `/oauth2/token` API. When a user is blocked, the default response looks like this:

```json
{
    "error_description": "1253 Account is locked for user: test1@test.com in user store: PRIMARY in tenant: carbon.super. Cannot login until the account is unlocked.",
    "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

My goal is to enhance this response by adding additional fields and customizing the error message. We have a custom template between the frontend and backend, and I want to leverage it for this purpose.

My questions are:

1. Is the approach of using a Custom Identity Event Handler suitable for this purpose?
2. How can I further customize the error message in the response from the `/oauth2/token` API using our custom template?

Any insights or guidance on best practices would be greatly appreciated.